# My Python program doesn't have file, edit, shell, debug options

Tags: python, python-idle

I've installed and re-installed Python 3.6.1. I am not given the options at the top like "file, edit, shell, debug, etc" at the top. I have no idea what to do at this point as I've searched around for a while and haven't come up with a solution. Does anyone have any idea of what I should do about this?

Comment: What do you call "your Python program"? What exactly did you start?

Comment: Then what is it showing?

Comment: Python is a programming language. Python interpreter is a console application. It has no options "on top", because it has no "top". What are you talking about? Some sort of a graphical program? Something like "PythonWin"? "Idle"? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows, at least, the console does not have a menu at the top.  When you run interactive python, there is no menu.  When you run a program that does not create a menu, there is no menu.  When you run an IDE such as IDLE, the IDE puts its menu at the top.  The particular menu entries you refer to occur on the IDLE menu.  So start IDLE from an icon or from a console.  For the latter, `<python> -m idlelib` should work, where ` refers to a python binary.  Some details depend on the OS.